# Send TAB in authotkey after every (letter)keypress regardless of language setting

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make filling some web-forms easier. Each form might include 100 times that tab would have to be pressed after typing a letter to be able to input the next letter to it's corresponding slot. I tried some examples, but ran in to problems when changing Windows language settings to Russian. Most of the time I will be inputting Russian letters, and if not, then just normal latin letters.

I tried following basic examples which worked for either one letter at a time or all (latin) letters at once.

```
#UseHook On
w::send ш{Tab}
```

Which outputs

```
Ñˆ(and one single TAB taking me to the next input)
```

So for some reason the characters are not correctly output from AHK.

This other example I found here and it works fine for any latin letter after a small modification:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/67948-detect-any-letter-key-press/

```
Loop 26

Hotkey, % Chr(A_Index+96),LatinLabel ;loop creating hotkeys for a-z

Return



LatinLabel:

Func(A_ThisHotkey)

Return



Func(var) {
#UseHook On
Send %var%{TAB}
}
```

I read that listening for all keypresses or actions would not be ideal, since this would also record mouse clicks and even movement.
So are there other alternatives googling didn't reveal to me?

Comment: I would check out the use of INPUT. See: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm  Here you can select after how many characters (in your case 1) the input buffer is tested, with V (visible) the typed characters are not only stored in the buffer but sent to the webform too. Just add a Send {Tab} for every correct character and loop back to INPUT again

Answer (score 1):

The problem of `ш` becoming `Ñˆ` is due to the script file having been saved as UTF-8 without BOM. You just need to save the file as UTF-8 with BOM. AutoHotkey (as of v1.1.30.03) interprets files without a BOM as ANSI, because the default editor is Notepad, and Notepad (prior to Windows version 1903) defaults to ANSI.

The second script registers hotkeys `a`-`z` via the expression `Chr(A_Index+96)`, which produces latin letters. Once registered, these hotkeys will activate when you press the corresponding virtual keys even if you change the keyboard layout. However, they will still send latin letters, because `A_ThisHotkey` is `a`-`z`.

The solution is to use the `~` hotkey modifier instead of sending the hotkey. In that case, pressing the key has whatever effect it should normally have, then the script sends Tab.

```
Loop 26
    Hotkey % "~" Format("vk{:02x}", A_Index+64), AzKey
return
AzKey:
Send {Tab}
return
```

This registers hotkeys for the virtual keys vk41 - vk5A, which correspond to A - Z on layouts which contain those characters, but also work with other layouts. However, there may be some other keys which produce "letters" or other characters you want to watch for; in that case, just register additional hotkeys as needed.

```
Hotkey ~vkC0, AzKey
```

or stack the labels

```
vkC0::
AzKey:
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems with sending Unicode characters?
For the euro symbol I use either of:

```
SendInput {U+20AC}
PostMessage, 0x102, 8364, 1, Edit1, A ;WM_CHAR
```